# Regex for matching a string with possible spaces at beginning and end of string with a hyphen in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to put together a js flavor of regex to match a string like in the following examples where there may be a whitespace at the front or back of the string, or both front and back. But not within the string

Examples:

```
'Z5LW-KRT2'       MATCH
' Z5LW-krt2'      MATCH
'Z5LW-KRT2 '      MATCH
' Z5LW-KRT2 '     MATCH

' Z5LW-K RT2 '    NO MATCH
```

So far i have come up with the below which matches if there is no whitespace anywhere, but i cant figure out how to include white space at the beginning or end but not within like in the examples

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$
```

Comment: `\s` is for spaces, `\S` is for anything other than spaces.

Comment: The regex you gave only matches `Z5LW-KRT2`, but yeah ... `^\s*\S+\s*$`.  (or `[A-Za-z0-9\-]` instead of `\S`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `\s*` to match spaces so the result regex should look like `^\s*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\s*$` and even you can reduce it to `^\s*[\w\-]+\s*$` if you want to use the build-in class `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Either
`^\s*\S+\s*$` or `^\s*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\s*$` will do what you need:

`^`: start of string
`\s*`: optional whitespace
`\S+`: at least 1 non-whitespace *OR*
`[A-Za-z0-9\-]`: match literal character classes
`\s*`: optional whitespace
`$`: end of string

```js
let tests = [ 'Z5LW-KRT2'  //     MATCH
            , ' Z5LW-krt2' //     MATCH
            , 'Z5LW-KRT2 ' //     MATCH
            , ' Z5LW-KRT2 ' //    MATCH
            , ' Z5LW-K RT2 ' //   NO MATCH
            ]
            
let regex1 = /^\s*\S+\s*$/
let regex2 = /^\s*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\s*$/

for (test of tests) {
  console.log(`[${test}] regex1: ${test.match(regex1)?'MATCH':'NO MATCH'}, regex2: ${test.match(regex2)?'MATCH':'NO MATCH'}`)
}
```